# IfModule filter_module Internal Server Error Apache 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The below code in .htaccess is causing 500 Internal Server Error.
I have tried updating the code to Apache 2.4 but seems like I did a mistake somewhere.

Please advise whats wrong with the below code that is causing this Error:

```
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} = text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} = application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)"
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
```

Tried this code as well and it didn't work:

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} =~ 'text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} =~ 'application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)'"
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion <= 2.2>
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>
```

After testing these two lines are the ones causing the 500 Internal Server Error:

```
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} =~ 'text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))'"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content-Type} =~ 'application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)'"
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason apache 2.4 wasn't supporting the more compact code!
Anyway for documentation and if anyone face the same problem here is the **WORKING** Solution: *(just mimic the changes)*

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/html|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/css|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/javascript|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/plain|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/xml|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^text/x-component|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/javascript|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/json|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/xml|"
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} =~ m|^application/x-javascript|"
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>

<IfVersion <= 2.2>
<IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /text/(html|css|javascript|plain|xml|x-component)/
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type /application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
</IfVersion>
```